# show_full_path not working in Mac

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I noticed there's a feature to show the full path to files in the title bar.

and I found it in the settings:

```
// Show the full path to files in the title bar.
// On OS X, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings, so
// you'll need to place this line in your user settings to override it.
"show_full_path": true,
```

However, I still can't see the full path. I think it'd be something to do with `On OS X, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings, so you'll need to place this line in your user settings to override it`.

But what should I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the setting in your user settings. Click on `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings-User`. At the top of the file, on the line after the opening brace `{`, put the following:

```json
"show_full_path": true,
```

and save the file.

If you open the `Settings-User` file and it is completely empty, then add the following:

```json
{
    "show_full_path": true
}
```

Save the file, and you should be all set.

Comment: That should be curly braces, should it not?